# Find limit with Riemann sum

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find

$\lim _{n\to \infty}\:\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$

I've turned it into
$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:\left(\frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{k}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\left(k+1\right)\pi }{n}\right)$

that I can also write, to match with how it is defined in my math class as: $\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:\left(a_{k+1}-a_{k}\right)\sin(\xi_k)$

with in this case $\xi_k = \frac{(k+1)\pi}{n}$ and so on...

However I'm stuck here, since according to my math classes $\xi_k$ is supposed to be in $[a_{k}, a_{k+1}]$ which it isn't.

What am I doing wrong? Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you multiply and divide by $\pi$?
$$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:\left(\frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{k}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\left(k+1\right)\pi }{n}\right)=\frac1\pi\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:\left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n}-\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\left(k+1\right)\pi }{n}\right)$$
That way $\xi_k$ is in the correct interval